# Dropdown menu blink issue

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with my dropdown menu. It blinks when you touch its top and both top sides. You can review sample here http://jsfiddle.net/bombula/TKwNS/.

Comment: Code reviews belong on programmers.stackexchange.com. If you're needing help, please try to be a bit more specific with what you've tried and what errors you see.

Comment: works fine for me could you say which browser you tried i am trying with chrome.

Comment: It's fine for me, too. (Mozilla)

Comment: Your problem doesn't happen on either of my machines. However, there is [another problem](http://imgur.com/HDFwe) that happens for me on `Chrome 21.0.1180.79` on Windows 7 (doesn't happen on Arch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrote this code
Hope it will help you

```
$(function () {
    $('.dropdown_menu').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul#submenu').slideDown("1000"); 
            });
    $('.dropdown_menu').mouseleave(
         function () {
                $('ul#submenu').stop().slideUp("1000"); 
            });
});​
```